# django hyperlink in custoom middleware not workiing

Tags: python, django, view, middleware

I have written a view:

```
class ShowNotifications(TemplateView):

context = {}
model = Notification
template_name = "notifications.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ShowNotifications,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['unseen_notifications'] = Notification.objects.filter(body__user=self.request.user).filter(viewed=False)
    context['seen_notifications'] = Notification.objects.filter(body__user=self.request.user).filter(viewed=True)
    return context
```

I have included the "notifications.html" in base.

My "notifications.html" looks like:

```
{% for notification in unseen_notifications %}
<a href="{% url "question-detail" notification.body.id notification.body.category.id notification.id %}">{{notification.title}}
</a>
{% endfor %}
{% for notification in seen_notifications %}
<a href="{% url "question-detail" notification.body.id notification.body.category.id notification.id %}">{{notification.title}}
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

When I call this view by url it works fine, when I click to the notification title it redirets to question detail page. 
I have included it in base. When I dont call the view by url, in base it shows the notification list but when I click it dont redirect to question detail page.

Whats wrong in here ??

Comment: Show us the relevant lines from `urls.py`.

Comment: One thing to check: load the notification list page the second way (without using the URL), then show the page source and make sure the `href` parameters make sense as URLs.

Comment: url(r'^notifications/', ShowNotifications.as_view(), name='notifin') ,

Comment: show us 'question-detail' in urls.py

Comment: url(r'^question/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<cpk>\d+)/(?:/(?P<npk>\d+))?',QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name="question-detail"),